# Laravel-Excel export

Tags: excel, laravel, export, mime-types, laravel-excel

I am trying to export an excel file from laravel. It works fine on my local server. But it is not working properly on the live server. It also stores the excel file in **"storage->framework->laravel-excel"** but not showing the download option. It throws 500 server error. I checked on my log file, it says **"production.ERROR: Unable to guess the MIME type as no guessers are available (have you enabled the php_fileinfo extension?)."**
Please help me, how can I solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable the php_fileinfo at php.ini and if you don't have access to it, ask your hosting provider to enable it for you. It is not a Laravel related issue, it is just the extension.

Comment: I add a "php.ini" file on my project folder and write "extension=php_fileinfo". But it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using cPanel?

Comment: Yes. I am using Cpanel

Comment: If it is already installed in your server, you need to navigate to Select PHP Version and from there, select the fileinfo checkbox under your selected version of php.

Comment: In my cpanel there is no "Select PHP Version" option

Comment: Contact your hosting provider than.